# is it possible to generate a list in list for desired numbers?

Tags: python, arrays, list, loops, matrix

I wanted to generate a `list` in `list` :

now, I have basically two options, either I `input` the `list` through a text file or I should generate the `list` by itself.

is it possible to generate this type of list by itself using nested loops?

```
[[0,0,0], [0,0,0] ,[0,0,0], [0,0,0,], [0,0,0]]
```

I wanted to put `-1` at the place of the middle zero of each sub-list like `[0, -1, 0]`, there are `5` sub-list so the `-1` should be inserted `5` times

so desired result would be

```
[[0,-1,0], [0,0,0] ,[0,0,0], [0,0,0,], [0,0,0]]
[[0,0,0], [0,-1,0] ,[0,0,0], [0,0,0,], [0,0,0]]
[[0,0,0], [0,0,0] ,[0,-1,0], [0,0,0,], [0,0,0]]
[[0,0,0], [0,0,0] ,[0,0,0], [0,-1,0,], [0,0,0]]
[[0,0,0], [0,0,0] ,[0,0,0], [0,0,0,], [0,-1,0]]
```

In my actual work, I have 38 sub-lists, for convenience, I showed only 5 here.

my attempt -

presently I am doing this by using `json.loads` and inputting this as a dictionary then collecting it using append and further converting it into a list and then I'll use those values.
however, this method seems so cumbersome to me.

```
F = []
import json
with open('unitvalue.txt') as f:  
        f_1 =   {int(key): json.loads(val) for key, val in json.loads(f.readline()).items()}
        f_2 =   {int(key): json.loads(val) for key, val in json.loads(f.readline()).items()}
        f_3 =   {int(key): json.loads(val) for key, val in json.loads(f.readline()).items()}
        f_4 =   {int(key): json.loads(val) for key, val in json.loads(f.readline()).items()}
        f_5 =   {int(key): json.loads(val) for key, val in json.loads(f.readline()).items()}
```

where `unitvalue.txt` contain

```
{"1":"[0,-1,0]", "2":"[0,0,0]","3":"[0,0,0]", "4":"[0,0,0]", "5":"[0,0,0]"}
{"1":"[0,0,0]", "2":"[0,-1,0]","3":"[0,0,0]", "4":"[0,0,0]", "5":"[0,0,0]"}
{"1":"[0,0,0]", "2":"[0,0,0]","3":"[0,-1,0]", "4":"[0,0,0]", "5":"[0,0,0]"}
{"1":"[0,0,0]", "2":"[0,0,0]","3":"[0,0,0]", "4":"[0,-1,0]", "5":"[0,0,0]"}
{"1":"[0,0,0]", "2":"[0,0,0]","3":"[0,0,0]", "4":"[0,0,0]", "5":"[0,-1,0]"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with a list comprehension:

```
n = 5
[[[0, -1, 0] if i == j else [0, 0, 0] for j in range(n)] for i in range(n)]
```

Output:

```
[[[0, -1, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]],
 [[0, 0, 0], [0, -1, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]],
 [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, -1, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]],
 [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, -1, 0], [0, 0, 0]],
 [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, -1, 0]]]
```

Comment: thank you, sir. @Nin

and sorry for asking such an easy question

Comment: Nice. It's easier to remember this way *if r == c* .   *r* is row, *c* is col (*j*)